Bad Request - Null Message - Error null from the ADF - Copy data Pipeline
Continuity to one of my previous question:
I have created the ADF Pipeline for copying the blob containers and its data inside between the storage accounts as shown below:

For-each activity settings:

Pipeline parameter is container_name
and its value is array type:
[
{
    "source_ctr":"app-backup",
    "target_ctr":"app-backup"
},
{
    "source_ctr":"azure-webjobs-hosts",
    "target_ctr":"azure-webjobs-hosts"
},
{
    "source_ctr":"azure-webjobs-secrets",
    "target_ctr":"azure-webjobs-secrets"
},
{
    "source_ctr":"data-app",
    "target_ctr":"data-app"
},
{
    "source_ctr":"data-apptemp",
    "target_ctr":"data-apptemp"
},
{
    "source_ctr":"data-uat",
    "target_ctr":"data-dev"
},
{
    "source_ctr":"db-backup",
    "target_ctr":"db-backup"
}
]

This is the 1st Copy Data activity - Source configuration for copying the containers between the storage accounts:

CopyData1 - Sink Configuration:

Copy Data 2 - Source Configuration:

Sink Configuration:

Created two data sets & linked services for source and destination storage account connections - Test Connection is successful.
When I run the pipeline, I'm getting this error:
{
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": null,
"target": "pipeline//runid/<alpha-numeric-value>",
"details": null,
"error": null
}

Pipeline in Json:
{
    "name": "AzBlobCtrDataCopyPipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.container_name",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "BinarySource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "wildcardFolderPath": "*",
                                        "deleteFilesAfterCompletion": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "BinarySink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings",
                                        "copyBehavior": "PreserveHierarchy"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "SrcSubscnBlobstorageds",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "container_name": {
                                            "value": "@item().source_ctr",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "DestnSubsnBlobstorageds",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "container_name": {
                                            "value": "@item().target_ctr",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data2",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Copy data1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "BinarySource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": false,
                                        "wildcardFileName": "*",
                                        "deleteFilesAfterCompletion": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "BinarySink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "SrcSubscnBlobstorageds",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "container_name": {
                                            "value": "@item().source_ctr",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "DestnSubsnBlobstorageds",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "container_name": {
                                            "value": "@item().target_ctr",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "sourceSAS": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "?hiddenSAStoken"
            },
          "destinationSAS": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "?hiddenSAStoken"
          },
            "container_name": {
                "type": "array",
                "defaultValue": [
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "app-backup",
                        "target_ctr": "app-backup"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "azure-webjobs-hosts",
                        "target_ctr": "azure-webjobs-hosts"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "azure-webjobs-secrets",
                        "target_ctr": "azure-webjobs-secrets"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "data-app",
                        "target_ctr": "data-app"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "data-apptemp",
                        "target_ctr": "data-apptemp"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "data-uat",
                        "target_ctr": "data-dev"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "db-backup",
                        "target_ctr": "db-backup"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubdev-applease",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdev-applease"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubdev-leases",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdev-leases"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuat-applease",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdev-applease"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuat-largemessages",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdev-largemessages"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuat-leases",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdev-leases"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatlocal-applease",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevlocal-applease"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatlocal-largemessages",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevlocal-largemessages"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatlocal-leases",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevlocal-leases"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatlocal2-applease",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevlocal2-applease"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatlocal2-largemessages",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevlocal2-largemessages"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatlocal2-leases",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevlocal2-leases"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatlocaln-applease",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevlocaln-applease"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatlocaln-leases",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevlocaln-leases"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatlocalnn-applease",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevlocalnn-applease"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatlocalnn-largemessages",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevlocalnn-largemessages"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatlocalnn-leases",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevlocalnn-leases"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatnn-applease",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevnn-applease"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatnn-largemessages",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevnn-largemessages"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatnn-leases",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevnn-leases"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatnnlocal-applease",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevnnlocal-applease"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatnnlocal-largemessages",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevnnlocal-largemessages"
                    },
                    {
                        "source_ctr": "taskhubuatnnlocal-leases",
                        "target_ctr": "taskhubdevnnlocal-leases"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2024-04-22T00:25:15Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}

Can anyone help me here what and where i'm doing the mistake.

This error message can happen for various reasons. It would be better if you could share the settings of for-each activity

https://i.imgur.com/txFUozV.png - for-each activity settings

What is the value given to the parameter?

Updated the question with the pipeline settings and parameters name and value.

When I reproduced the same approach which you have provided, I didn't get any error, pipeline run successfully, could you please share your pipeline Json for more information?

Hi @Bhavani, Please check the question as we updated with pipeline json data also where we hidden the sas token.

The provided Json also working for me without any error he is the pipeline.

Let me check from my end once again

Hi Bhavani and Aswin, thanks for you diagnosis. It worked. There is bad configuration on my end.


When I was defining the pipeline parameter, I missed the '@', which resulted in the error shown above. After defining the parameter as @pipeline().parameters.container_name, my pipeline ran successfully without any errors.

Ensure that you have defined parameters with the correct syntax.
Check that there are no syntax errors in the pipeline.
Configure the pipeline correctly.

For more information, you can refer to the MS Q&A.
